# Getting time left

Tags: php

I have a time left function that I am using to get the time left based on a sent parameter.  My issue is I am having difficulty calculating if there is a day, a year, or a month left.

Function:

```
  function get_time_difference_php_left($created_time)
 {
        $str = strtotime($created_time);
        $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

        // It returns the time difference in Seconds...
        $time_differnce = $today-$str;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Years...
        $years = 60*60*24*365;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Months...
        $months = 60*60*24*30;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Days...
        $days = 60*60*24;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Hours...
        $hours = 60*60;

        // To Calculate the time difference in Minutes...
        $minutes = 60;

        if(intval($time_differnce/$years) > 1)
        {
            return " - ". intval($time_differnce/$years)." years left";
        }else if(intval($time_differnce/$years) > 0)
        {
            return " - ".intval($time_differnce/$years)." year left";
        }else if(intval($time_differnce/$months) > 1)
        {
            return " - ".intval($time_differnce/$months)." months left";
        }else if(intval(($time_differnce/$months)) > 0)
        {
            return " - ".intval(($time_differnce/$months))." month left";
        }else if(intval(($time_differnce/$days)) > 1)
        {
            return " - ".intval(($time_differnce/$days))." days left";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$days)) > 0) 
        {
            return " - ".intval(($time_differnce/$days))." day left";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$hours)) > 1) 
        {
            return " - ".intval(($time_differnce/$hours))." hours left";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$hours)) > 0) 
        {
            return " - ".intval(($time_differnce/$hours))." hour left";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$minutes)) > 1) 
        {
            return " - ".intval(($time_differnce/$minutes))." minutes left";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce/$minutes)) > 0) 
        {
            return " - ".intval(($time_differnce/$minutes))." minute left";
        }else if (intval(($time_differnce)) > 1) 
        {

            return " - ".intval(($time_differnce))." seconds left";
        }else
        {
            return " - few seconds left";
        }
  }
```

If I run this based on the now time and a date time of: `2014-04-17 03:27:26` it will tell me `88 years`.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Just tried this with your example date string and it said 27 days

Comment: @robjingram Ya I see that, its doing that for me to, strange because that is not correct?

Comment: That is correct?  Why is it not?  March 17th to April 13th is 27 days.

Comment: Worth following something like the answer below so you get the remaining hours etc. too

Comment: @robjingram: He'd have to use the int remainder somehow so it doesn't show 27*24 hours, etc.

Comment: @robjingram also note that the 27 days is calcuating how long it has `been` rather than the time remaining to that date.  I actually meant that date to be a 4 not a 3.

Comment: So I should get 3 or 4 days left to the 17 of this month.

Comment: I added an answer about your backwards calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had March initially.  You are doing the calculation backwards then.  Your code should show expiration date, not creation date.  If you are trying to use an expiration date, then your code should use:

```
$time_differnce = $str - $today;
```

You can use the modulus (remainder) operator in each if to show the next value as well.  For example if you have 3.7 days, you use 3 days and then `.7*$hours`.

Comment: No problem, I added an update about modulus from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php to give you more accurate numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Change all else if statements to if's

Change from:

```
if(intval($time_differnce/$years) > 1) {
    return " - ". intval($time_differnce/$years)." years left";
} else if (intval($time_differnce/$years) > 0) {
```

to

```
if(intval($time_differnce/$years) > 1) {
    return " - ". intval($time_differnce/$years)." years left";
} 
if (intval($time_differnce/$years) > 0) {
```

Comment: There is no reason to remove the else ifs.

Comment: when you have return statements anything after the if is an else.